# MongoDB Distributed transactions

Tags: python, mongodb, transactions, distributed

Working on MongoDB and am required to roll back once something in the route goes wrong.

I've read about something called two-phase commit in distributed transactions but didn't find any examples...

Can somebody let me understand how to use distributed transactions in Python using MongoDB? I need to use transactions between different services & databases.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: From the MongoDB manual: _"With distributed transactions, transactions can be used across multiple operations, collections, databases, documents, and shards."_. See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/core/transactions/